# How to preprocess a dataset with multiple input variables for integration with Tensorflow for binary classification?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, neural-network

I am trying to setup a minimum viable neural network to train for a binary classification task. I am importing a CSV file with seven total columns, the first column is the true label, 1 or -1. I have divided the dataset into a training set and test set. Additionally, I have been able to import the dataset into python, and normalize the six variables to numbers between zero and one.

I have been spending the past few hours developing ad hoc, layers for a neural network. I have been able to get the network to feedforward, and to make binary predictions. However, I am totally at a loss for how to train the model because I cannot figure out how to update the weights. Generally, I am familiar with back-propagation, SGD, derivates, ADAM, and the perceptron learning rule. The problem is I have been unable to figure out how to implement any of these methods, so my program learns.

In short, my goal is to update the weights of the neural network if the predict label and true label are not the same, so the network can learn.

I have tried using Keras because it is a high level API. https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/basic_classification#build_the_model While keras is good for getting started, it is very difficult to use Keras or Tensorflow on the datasets I generated myself. I am having trouble reformatting a neural network for the MNIST dataset to the needs of my present task https://medium.com/@brian.s.haney44/computer-vision-b39256f13fa4. I was hoping to complete the task with the Python standard library. Further, I have looked into and researched matrix multiplication vs. linear models for feedforward propagation, as well as derivative calculators and the perceptron learning rule for for weight updates. I created a Github https://github.com/Bhaney44/Deep-Neural-Network repo for the project with a sample dataset for illustrative purposes.

'''

```
    #Input Array
    input_array = (true_label, var_1, var_2, var_3)

    #Input layer with three nodes and a normalization function
    def input_layer():
        x_1 = (input_array[1])/float(100)
        x_2 = (input_array[2])/float(100)
        x_3 = (input_array[2])/float(100)

        #Hidden layer
        def hidden_layer():
            w_0 = 0.1
            w_1 = 0.1
            w_2 = 0.1
            w_3 = 0.1
            x_4 = (x_1 * w_0)+(x_2 * w_1)
            x_5 = (x_2 * w_2)+(x_3 * w_3)

            #Output layer
            def output_layer():
                w_4 = 0.1
                w_5 = 0.1
                x_6 = (x_4 * w_4)+(x_5 * w_5)

                #Activation function
                def activation():
                    #True label
                    x_0 = input_array[0]
                    #decision function
                    if x_6 > 0.5:
                        y = 1
                    else:
                        y = -1

                    #activation function
                    if y is x_0:
                        #Here the network predicted right
                        print('correct')
                    else:
                        #Here I want to adjust the weigh parameters
                        #However, I am not sure where to start
                        #Ideas include
                            #calculate loss function
                            #change weights structure
                            #use matrices instead of coefficients
                        print('update weights')

                activation()
            output_layer()
        hidden_layer()
    input_layer()
```

'''

My expectation is to find a way to update the weights, so the network can learn from training data and be applied to new data. The results are as I expect because I put a print function as a placeholder for the weight update algorithm. I am just not sure how to link functions together or to change numbers within the program automatically. I would sincerely appreciate any help, advice, suggestions, or criticisms.

With thanks,

Brian

Comment: Please clarify what exactly your question is. Are you trying to write a NN from scratch? Or are you trying to use Tensorflow or Keras? Also, what does that link from medium have to do with your question

Comment: Thanks that was helpful. The link from medium are convolutional neural network s I did some hobbying/research with, which has to do with this question because I am trying to build a neural network, but those two neural nets are built specifically for the MNIST dataset - which is my problem. I guess for me the first two questions are a bit dichotomous. I am trying to run my data through a neural network, my question is how do I build a neural network to do that? This question isn't so much about Keras or Numpy as much as it is about me trying to learn how to take data end-to-end. Thanks.